# What is the in-core part of a file?

Tags: files, synchronization

From the manual on [fsync](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/man2/fsync.2.html):

> fsync - synchronize  a file's complete in-core state with that on disk
>
> fsync copies all **in-core** parts of a file to disk, and waits  until  the device  reports   that all parts are on stable storage.  It also updates metadata stat information.

What exactly is this "in-core" part of a file? Is it the content that has been modified, but only in memory, not on disk?

Comment: "core" is another name for volatile memory (RAM), because it was originally made out of magnetic core. This [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html) has a better explanation for what fsync(2) is doing.

Comment: Thanks @UncleBilly. This is a perfectly legitimate answer. I'll accept it if you post it below.

Comment: @UncleBilly core is not a name for volatile memory. It is a name for primary read/write memory. Now implemented with RAM, but it was implemented with ferrite cores. It was non-volatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core was the old primary read/write memory.

Now implemented with RAM, but it was implemented with ferrite cores. It was non-volatile.

Core now refers to primary read/write memory (RAM), whether volatile or not.